# Sql Server jobs using maintenance task(SSIS)

Tags: sql

How do i see jobs content that are created using Maintenance tasks(SSIS). I have Index Rebuild job thats failing. I wanted to see what TSQL script that was created for this job. I right click on the job and checked the step. But it was not giving me enough info. It was created using the ssis task. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You would have to open up the SSIS pacakge to see what it does, it may or may not use a t-sql script.